# Faradays law of induced emf

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Let's assume that I have an ideal conductor(straight wire(, as we know that potential at any point on the ideal conductor is the same, if i place that ideal conductor in a region where magnetic field is increasing, so according to faradays law a potential difference will exist across the ends of the conductor, but how is that possible if we know that for an ideal conductor potential at any point is the same

Comment: Can you define a potential in a region of space with varying magnetic field?

Comment: If nobody answers, I'll give you an answer this evening (CET)